# Animação da div, sem CSS3 para posição futura

Tags: jquery, css3, animação

Tenho uma suposta galeria de produtos, com divs alinhadas usando `{display: block; float: left;}`

Eu fiz com que algumas divs desapareçam dependendo do menu selecionado usando `fadeOut()` e reapareçam com `fadeIn()`.
Criei esse código para que isso aconteça:

```
var tipo="all";
$('a.type').click(function(){
    $('a.type').removeClass('Bolding');
    $(this).addClass('Bolding');

    tipo=$(this).attr('id');
    $(".imagem").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass(tipo) || tipo=="all"){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }else{
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }
    })

})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/williammustaffa/Sn46E/)

Quando as divs somem elas ganham o valor `{display:none}` desaparecendo da página. o problema é que as outras divs simplesmente pulam para a posição futura. E eu queria que elas fizessem uma animação até a próxima posição se encaixando. Tomem como exemplo [este plugin](http://mixitup.io/), só que ele é pago.

Não quero usar CSS3 pela compatibilidade.

Comment: Seria bom colocar um trecho de código no jsFiddle para facilitar a busca da solução por outras pessoas. Acho que fica até melhor pois facilita a integração da resposta com seu código.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/williammustaffa/Sn46E/
Aqui está :D

Comment: Show, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Achei um plugin externo, tem problema? Caso não tenha vou adapta-lo ao seu código e posto uma resposta.

Comment: Se for um plugin free, facilitaria muito! Não tem problema! Agradeceria! :D

Comment: Ok, vou preparar aqui e posto.

Comment: Pode me mandar o nome do plugin? :D

Comment: Ah sim, eu tava tentando fazer o source sem utilizar html5 (já que não quer css3).

Achei 2 plugins: o QuickSand (http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) e o Shuffle (http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/)

Além disso tem o Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) mas ele é pago para uso comercial (barato)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma array de posições. Cada item da array tem valores de posição (top e left). Ao reorganizar, anime os elementos para a posição alvo.

Se você puder colocar um id em cada elemento facilitará muito, por dois motivos: a lógica fica mais simples e o código fica mais rápido, pois recuperar elementos pela id demora menos.

Com as ids, crie uma array com a ordem dos elementos. Ao esconder um elemento, remova-o desta lista. No final, pegue a lista com os elementos que sobraram e mova-os!

Você também vai notar que no seu exemplo as divs possuem posição absoluta. Você vai precisar dessa propriedade para mover os elementos livremente.

http://jsfiddle.net/vzCj7/

```
var tipo="all";
var posicoes = [[0,0],[0,80],[80,0],[80,80]];

    $('a.type').click(function(){

        var elementos = ['a','b','c','d'];
        var alterados = [];

        $('a.type').removeClass('Bolding');
        $(this).addClass('Bolding');

        tipo=$(this).attr('id');
        $(".imagem").each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass(tipo) || tipo=="all"){
                $(this).fadeIn();
            }else{
                $(this).fadeOut();

                var elId = $(this).attr('id');
                var meuIndice = elementos.indexOf(elId); 
                elementos.splice(meuIndice,1);

            }
        })

        for (i in elementos){

            var meuIndice = elementos.indexOf(elementos[i]);

            alvoY = posicoes[meuIndice][0];
            alvoX = posicoes[meuIndice][1];

            console.log('elemento '+elementos[i]+' deve ir para '+alvoX+' e '+alvoY);

             $('#'+elementos[i]).animate({
                 top: alvoY,
                 left: alvoX,
             }, 1000);

        }

    })
```